# firemonkey xe3 xe2 TPath

Tags: delphi, graphics, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

when executed follow code Path is shapely in xe2 but absurd in xe3.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Path : TPath;
begin
  Path := TPath.Create(Self);
  Path.Parent :=self;
  Path.Data.Data :=
  'M44.093,34.558v-2.83h12.793c4.131,0,8.301,3.841,8.301,8.969c0,4.375-2.829,7.607-6.49,8.462l8.106,8.105'+
    'c5.475-3.377,9.456-9.446,9.456-16.705c0-9.971-7.978-19.658-18.804-19.658H32.697v2.262L44.093,34.558z';


end;
```

Comment: Why is not it working in XE3? Is there something I do not know?

Comment: Show us how it is not working and what `TPath` is. Right now, your code is a string assignment to properties of some `TPath` object without explaining where it comes from (is it a Windows path, a wanderers path?). Please elaborate.

Comment: TPath is a built in component of FireMonkey for rendering vector paths. I'm really not sure why some on here feel the need to attack newbies so ferociously, especially when they don't understand the technology the questioner is asking about.

Comment: @Mike I see no ferocity here. Question would benefit from a demo of what is wrong, e.g. screenshot. We don't like questions that just say "it doesn't work".

Comment: Are you really executing that code? I found [reference to an IDE issue](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=467653) where editing the path data in the property editor yields incorrect results.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TPathData.Data) says shapes are separated by commas or spaces; your code uses neither. The documentation doesn't call for any separation between a letter the following number, but all examples I've seen include at least one space, and I've also read that [the path-data parser prefers spaces before any negative numbers](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=437728).

Comment: I added Path data from svg file